# In WCF Data Services, how can I limit the entities visible to the consumer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

My Init method looks like this

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
}
```

However, I know there is a way to limit the client from seeing the 100 entities in my data model. I only want to expose four! Maybe the Init() methods has nothing to do with it. **How do you do it?**

Comment: Are you asking how to restrict your service so that only 4 entities are visible out of the 100 entity types you have defined? config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead); controls just that. Except you're setting read visibility on ALL (*) of your entities. If you only want 4, you should just name the 4 entities you want to expose instead of *

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the line

```
 config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
```

and replace it with setting the desired access on your individual entity sets.
Example here: [MSDN: DataServiceConfiguration.SetEntitySetAccessRule Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.setentitysetaccessrule%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)